# confusion in forming constraints to the product manufacturaing problem of operations research

Tags: operations-research

In the OR problem statement attached below I am confused about the constraints to this problem.

The constraint on manufacturing is 10 hours of production per day.

so, if x->quantity of product 1 manufactured/day
y->quantity of product 2 manufactured/day

then why the constraints is on each process(total time) <=10 hours i.e.

process 1(total time)<=600
or 10x+5y<=600

and not on total time taken to produce x quantity of product 1 by all three processes <=10 hours

i.e.

10x+6x+8x<=600

please clarify this.

[image: Or problem statement]